# Move SVN project within repository without checkout

Tags: svn, repository, project, move

Suppose you have this SVN repository structure

```
Root
    Foo
        Project1
        Project2
    Bar
        Project3
```

And you want to move Project1 to the top level:

```
Root
    Foo
        Project2
    Bar
        Project3
    Project1
```

The developers already have Project1 at the top level of their local folder trees, so there's no point in moving them, and you'd like to accomplish this without requiring the developers to do checkouts etc. (which would force them to deal with lots of unversioned files).

Is this possible?

We're using Tortoise SVN, but we don't have a problem using svn.exe if that's necesary.

TIA

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Best thing would be to do an SVN move, to move the Project1 under root, and do an SVN switch on the already checked out ones.

Moving the Project1

```
svn move -m "message" http://<svn-url>/Foo/Project1 http://<svn-url>/Project1
```

Switching already checked-out repositories on local machines

```
svn switch http://<svn-url>/Project1
```

You can use TortoiseSVN to do the same.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Move the project using the repository explorer, and ask the developers to switch to the new location (right-click, TortoiseSVN, Switch). It would be easier for them if they don't have any uncommitted files. Ask them to commit before moving the project.

Comment: If they can switch then it shouldn't matter if they have uncommitted changes or not, but it's always worth committing (even if it's to a new branch) for safety.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `svn mv` command. Just specify the source and the destination as URLs.
Use `svn switch` to update a working copy to a different URL.